# How to share Controller for different types of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website, which has 3 types of contact forms, each contact form is associated with a model.

1. Enquiry
2. Complaint
3. Join

They all inherit from a bass class (`AbstractContact`) which implements my `IContact` interface (EG, `Enquiry` extends `AbstractContact` and `AbstractContact` implements `IContact`).

This means in my Make_A_Complaint view, my model is of type Models.Complaint, where as in the Join_Us view, my model is of type Models.Join...

It would be nice for them all to route through a single method in my Controller. Something like

```
public ActionResult ContactUs(Models.Contact.IContact model)
```

which I can then cast to the desired type.

However, MVC doesn't appear to let me use either interfaces or abstract classes as the parameter.

What other option is there? Is my only option to create multiple methods in the controller, such as

```
public ActionResult SendEnquiry(Models.Contact.Enquiry model)

public ActionResult SendComplaint(Models.Contact.Complaint model)  

public ActionResult SendJoin(Models.Contact.Join model)
```

I don't believe I'm allowed to overload this so I can't have

```
public ActionResult Send(Models.Contact.Enquiry model)

public ActionResult Send(Models.Contact.Complaint model)  

public ActionResult Send(Models.Contact.Join model)
```

Comment: Its not possible using the `DefaultModelBinder` (which needs to initialize and instance of your model using `Activator.CreateInstace()` which only works for concrete types). You can however create a custom ModelBinder that reads the values in the request and initializes an instance (but you would need some property which distinguishes them)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a different controller for each type, inheriting from your current controller.

```
public abstract BaseContactController<T> where T : AbstractContract, IContact
{
    public virtual ActionResult ContactUs(T model)
    {
    }
}
```

Then one controller per model type:

```
public EnquiryController : BaseContactController<Models.Contact.Enquiry> 
{
    // actions are in the base class
}

public ComplaintController : BaseContactController<Models.Contact.Complaint> 
{
}

public JoinController : BaseContactController<Models.Contact.Join> 
{
}
```

So you have shared code in the base class, but different URLs and models

```
/enquiry/contactus
/complaint/contactus
/join/contactus
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the use of an interface in model binding would be a bad idea regardless to whether or not you *could* do it.

You presumably want to do this because the models share a core group of properties which are required by each of the three specified actions. If that's the case, why not inherit all three models from a base view model and use that as your model binding object?

As a side-note, I would actually recommend against doing this. Each of those three actions have a distinct job, and attempting to tie them all up into a single method breaks the single responsibility principle. If they share a lot of code, centralise the code in question and call this from each of the methods.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph cannot work - the `DefaultModelBinder` would only initialize an instance of the base view model, not the concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net mvc mapping post data to model by name. Let's say for example if all your models has fields Email, Name, Phone
You can create new model

```
public class ContactUsPostModel {
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
}
```

And use this model in your controller

`public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsPostModel model)`